# Error in echoing inside a td element

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am trying to see if an array is empty, so in a `<td>` I will write: Not Available.
I have this PHP/PDO code:

```
$sql1= "SELECT SUM(total_pay) AS total_w FROM workers WHERE date_of_pay = :d1 AND projects_id = :id";
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);

    $stmt1->bindValue(":d1", $d);
    $stmt1->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $count1 = $stmt1->execute();
    $result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
    $num1 = $stmt1->rowCount();
```

This is my html code:

```
<?php if($num1==0):?>
<td align="center">Not Available</td>
<?php else: ?>
<td align="center">
<?php 
{
    foreach ($result1 as $res1)
    {
        echo $res1['total_w'];
    }
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

When the array is not empty, I have a value, it will be shown in `<td>` normally but when `num1` is empty ($num1==0), nothing is shown in `<td>` even the text of `Not Available`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from [the documentation on `PDO::rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

It ***does not*** return the rowcount of the result-set of a SELECT query. That being said: you're `SELECT`'ing  a `SUM`, so the result-set will always be there (if the query was successful). If no records were `SUM`'ed, the value will be `NULL`, though. What you should do then is:

```
$result = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//SUM is only 1 row anyway

if ($result['total_w'] === null) {
    //no records found, no sum to display
} else {
    echo $result['total_w'];//show result
}
```

Checking the `total_w` key `=== null` (type and value check) does rely on the fact that you've set the `PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS` to `PDO::NULL_NATURAL` though. If you haven't, [use `PDO::setAttribute` to do so](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)